# How to resolve the Unresolved Compilation problem in Java?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

```
class one
{
    void call()
    {
        System.out.println(" A method");
    }
}
class two extends one
{
    void call()
    {
        System.out.println(" B method");
    }
}

public class Dispatch{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        one a=new one();
        two b=new two();
        one r;
        r=a;
        r.call();
        r=b;
        r.call();
    }
}
```

IDE used: VSCode

This was an attempt to implement runtime polymorphism. I used the same example used in "Java -the complete reference -Herbert Schildt", but it shows an error:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        Type mismatch: cannot convert from two to one".
```

Comment: it needs to be the base class

Comment: @dev7060 thanks sir.......missed that statement ..this being my 1st question to this legendgary portal..i missed it by-mistake. However the error is still the same.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Meaning: add the except stack trace. Besides, it sounds that you want to RUN your code, although it doesnt compile. Yet, the source code looks correct. So, first: ensure this compiles. If not, carefully read the error message you get from the compiler.

Comment: unrelated: follow java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase. And use meaningful names. one / two ... really dont say anything. Why not Base and Derived, or Parent + Child ...

Comment: And sorry, but also see: https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Comment: @GhostCat thank you for giving me insights on how to post.....thank u very much sir/mam.....your comment is very helpful in providing me the insights to StackOverFlow as I am a begineer here. Secondly the program compiles well on eclipse but not on vscode hence i posted this question.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend that you drop that book by Herbert Schildt, it is a pretty bad book, and Herbert Schildt is known for writing books that are riddled with errors and outright bad advice.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you for pointing that out sir But I think  the program is working fine on Eclipse...im sure its something about VSCode I don't know of which is causing the error....

Comment: @MarkRotteveel SIr , Can you recommend me a JAVA learning book ?

Comment: The code you provided worked well on my machine(Windows10; VS Code1.50.1; JDK11), can you post your settings if this question still exist?

Comment: @MollyWang Sir I am having the specs(Win 10;VS Code 1.50.1; Open JDk 11.0.8).My settings.json looks as : {} i.e its blank file no changes made....I suppose this is what you meant by settings...

Comment: Have you tried clean the workspace and run it again, is there any difference?

Comment: @MollyWang thanks very much sir, the problem was resolved on cleaning the workspace...

Comment: Okay, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Your example compiles and runs without errors on my machine (using Eclipse).

Some ideas: Maybe your IDE is set to recompile only on manual request (instead of the typical default continuous building). Or maybe your IDE has some weird compiler warning settings configured.